# How can I get the newest build of clojurescript working with lein-cljsbuild (without forking)?

Tags: clojurescript

I'm happily using `lein cljsbuild` right now to compile my clojurescript but I'm noticing that  the clojurescript library is changing quite rapidly and cljsbuild has fallen behind. Is there an option that we can put into `project.clj` that compiles against the newest clojurescript build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just add it as a dependency in your `project.clj`, e.g. `[org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-1835"]`.

Bigger example:

```
(defproject cljs-tests "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-1835"]]

  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "0.3.2"]]

  :cljsbuild ...)
```